# Login from Angular app using Duende BFF login endpoint

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server, duende, ionic-enterprise-auth

How to implement login authentication using Angular and Duende BFF?
I've set up the BFF client in Duende IS and when I hit BFF login from my angular app, it works but it redirects to BFF, not the angular app. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

pass a redirectUrl querystring parameter to the call to login, as long as it is a relative path it will be fine.

you can also override the default ILoginService implementation in your startup:
services.AddTransient<ILoginService, MyCustomLoginService>();

and in the ProcessRequestAsync method of that service modify the redirectUri as you see fit (look to the DefaultLoginService implementation)

I would recommend either to have some redirect-uri options in your config or make sure the redirecturi is in the caller's domain to avoid open redirects.